# How do I escape the HTML from being parsed as HTML?

Tags: freemarker

I need to write a help article that contains HTML examples. How do I escape the HTML from being parsed as HTML in Freemarker?

For example:

```
<ol>
     <li>List item 1</li>
     <li>List item 2</li>
     <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```

I can't find anything in regard to code fences or escaping HTML.

Comment: Read this page: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_html

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't parse them as HTML (it doesn't care, it's just text to output for it), the browser does, unless you escape those tags. FreeMarker can do HTML-escaping either via auto-escaping (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html), or if you aren't using automatic escaping (usually you should), then via `${example?html}`.